# Mysql_query setting new value to one more than the last

Tags: php, html, mysql

Im working with a database to create a like system. All was working fine until I added a function which adds a like each time a person likes a post. It is a mysql_query where I set the old likes to the new likes plus one.

It looks like this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `news` SET `post_likes` = `post_likes` + 1 WHERE `post_id` = $post_id");
```

This is the whole function:

```
function add_like($post_id){
    $post_id = (int)$post_id;
    mysql_query("UPDATE `news` SET `post_likes` = `post_likes` + 1 WHERE `post_id` = $post_id");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `likes` (`id` , `post_id`) VALUES (".$_SESSION['id'].", $post_id)");
}
```

The plus one is what I suspect is going wrong. When I print out the post_likes it prints out the correct value.

It is adding 9 to each value instead of 1.

Any Ideas why this could be happening? I may be over looking something so simple.

Thanks all!

Comment: are you sure you're not doing this in a loop... the query look right

Comment: [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) has been deprecated.

Comment: Is `post_likes` a numeric type?

Comment: Put more from your code, this piece look alright and the problem may be in some other place.

Comment: I use this at the top of the function it is in: $post_id = (int)$post_id;

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you pick PDO [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Okay Ill be sure too look that up thank you!

Comment: For mysqli there is a quick tutorial here: http://www.phphaven.com/article.php?id=65 It's not massively dissimilar to how you use mysql_* so shouldn't take much to adjust to